# Why does Gus walk away from his car?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad S04E12 [End Times](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1683087/), at the end Gus walks towards his car at the hospital parking with his two bodyguards, with Walt watching from an adjacent rooftop. As Gus is approaching the car he stops dead in his track with a doomed look on his face and heads over to the railing. He looks around but is not able to see Walt or sense anything out of place (*as far as the viewers can tell*). But he still walks away from the rigged car.

How does Gus sense that there's something wrong with the car? Moreover, Gus is never shown to be paranoid or doing things over a hunch, so how is this explainable?

Comment: Gus could have seen Walt's glasses reflecting back at him. They were on top of his head at a perfect angle to reflect the sun's rays.

Comment: @Robert: That was my initial thought but then, we never see that being explained in the show. And absolutely nothing goes unexplained in this show!

Comment: Maybe he saw Walt's head moving out of the corner of his eye. His brain registered it as a danger but his conscious mind didn't pick up exactly what was seen.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From this [source](http://www.pajiba.com/tv_reviews/breaking-bad-end-times-the-hard-part-about-playing-chicken-is-knowing-when-to-flinch.php):

> **"Walt was right when he said that Gus is always 10 moves ahead. Gus didn't need to be right about his car being sabotaged; he was just smart enough to know that he was walking into what would be a perfect trap, and one he’d happily spring if the tables were turned. So he walked away."**

Basically Gus wasn't sure if his car had been rigged to blow, but he knew if he was trying to kill someone it would have been a perfect way of achieving this.

He is clearly very good at reading situations and this lead to him being so successful in such a dangerous industry.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure Jesse tells him about the poison. Gus knows he didn't do it and is therefore on edge.

Comment: Right; knowing that the poisoning (which he didn't do) drew him out to such an unfamiliar location, Gus (rightly) suspected someone (Walt or not) might have set-up this opportunity.

Comment: ok, but why was gus so stupid to have only 1 cook. what if jesse dies due to car accident or something, does he wants to shut down his millon dollar industry due to just 1 cook?

Comment: @user6547 because he had a really hard time finding Gale, then Gale died so he *had* to use Walt and Jessie. For whatever reason it was hard for him to find reliable, qualified cooks he could trust. I'm sure he wanted other cooks, but had trouble finding them.

Comment: Followup question: Why wouldn't Gus have left one of his men in hiding to watch his car?

Comment: @JamieHanrahan I'd imagine it wasn't until Gus was approaching his car that he realised this could be a trap. If he thought it was a trap from the outset he would've left a man watching his car but he didn't realise it until the last minute.

Comment: Was that also a reason for Gus to let Jesse take a break, but kidnap him as soon as he left the custody?

Answer (score 14):

As we know, *Gus* is an extremely careful and intelligent man and he is in fact always ahead of *Walt* and everyone else. And I think it was exactly the fact that *Brock* was poisoned (which we know *Gus* didn't do) that made him doubt the situation, which is told to him by *Jesse* during their meeting right before.

> **Jesse:** He's not sick, he was poisoned.
>   **Gus:** How did that happen?
>   **Jesse:** The doctors, they don't know.

So he learns that *Brock* was poisoned by *unknown circumstances*. *Gus* might even guess it was *Walt* or not or that *Jesse* is in on anything or not, but what he knows is that definitely some kind of foul play was at the works and ultimately ended up bringing him here. So I think this was the primary hint that something was wrong with this whole hospital visit. And in fact after he is told of the poisoning he immediately gives in, lets *Jesse* stay in the hospital and leaves, though he doesn't seem to think about an actual car bomb until on his way to it.

Answer (score 3):

The entire situation (being lured to the hospital by Jesse,leaving his vehicle unguarded,etc) seemed rather odd to Fring. While he did make a serious tactical mistake (he walked to the edge of the parking structure and looked over, thus potentially exposing himself to a sniper) he seems to have gotten a bad feeling about things and decided not to drive away in his car.

Upon reflection, this actually is more a affectation of the narrative than a practical exercise as later (SPOILER) when Walt and Tio Salamanca use the same explosive device to finally murder Fring, it is clear that it’s explosive effect of the bomb would have been sufficient to seriously injure or kill Fring had he walked as close to his vehicle as he did. There was only a limited need (primarily for the sake of the series) for him to actually get into his car.

Comment: *"had he walked as close to his vehicle as he did"* - I don't think so. He stood at least like 5-10m away from his car and he stood right next (~1m) to Tio (and even that let at least "half of him" intact).

Comment: The explosion destroyed an entire room. It’s a certainty that coupled with the flammable liquid in the gas tank, an external explosion would have been significant enough to kill him.

Comment: I know this is nearly six years old at this point, but, c'mon. No way was that bomb big enough to kill him from there.

Answer (score -2):

Walt used the walkie talkie to detonate the bomb. When he turned it on Gus could hear the background noise's and Walt talking to himself.

Comment: I just rewatched the episode, and nothing in the scene suggests this. The accepted answer seems more probable.